# Error: The Configuration Section 'system.applicationHost/sites' cannot be read because it is a missing section declaration

Tags: iis, iis-6, applicationhost

I am trying to open sites in Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager. But there is an error message and I cannot open it. I reopen the IIS manager as Admin, but same issue occur. How can I solve this. Please Help.

[image: Error]

Comment: Nothing special. The file `applicationHost.config` is corrupt and you need to either find a previous working copy to replace it, or reinstall IIS. Hint: IIS Manager is looking for this line https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager/blob/master/Tests.JexusManager/original.config#L58 and that's why it says an error happened.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't previous copy. I will reinstall IIS.

Comment: I suggest you delete the old version of applicationhost.config before reinstalling. I'm not sure if the file will be deleted during uninstallation, but it's better to delete it for insurance.